# Is MapReduce any faster than doing the map and reduce in JS?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mapreduce

I'm using MongoDB with Node.js. Is there any speed advantage to using a MapReduce in Mongo as opposed to getting the full result set and doing a map and reduce in JS on my own?

Comment: If you want to run m/r faster, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-jsModeflag will be helpful. This is adopted after MongoDB v2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is usually no performance advantage to retrieving the entire resultset and performing the m/r app-side. In fact, in almost all situations cramming the entire resultset in memory on your node server is a particularly bad idea.

Doing the map/reduce on MongoDB will make sure no bandwidth between the database and your app server is wasted on retrieving the resultset and writing back the results of your m/r. MongoDB's map/reduce can also be easily scaled up.

TL;DR : Always do it in MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

If your database is on a different host than your server, the transfer of data will be smaller, which will waste less bandwidth and time.

Comment: MongoDB m/r isn't natively implemented but runs within MongoDB's JS context.

Answer (score 0):

The actual transfer of data can be costly and time consuming.  Imagine if everytime you wanted to do an inventory count you shipped all your items to another warehouse.

Also you have to factor in how things will scale.

- With mongodb you will typically want at least one replica for your data and that will add performance for read based tasks.
- With node you probably wont need to add a second server for a good while due to how well it scales.  Adding an intensive task to it could cause you to need to expand the amount of node servers facing outwards.